# SQL query multiple rows into single row that has JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to combine multiple rows into a single row that involves a `JOIN`. I cannot figure how to get the `JOIN` piece to work.

I am on SQL Server 2014.

This piece works great where I am rolling rows into a single comma separated line based on `ID_REVIEW`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      ID_REVIEW
      , STUFF((
      SELECT N', ' + CAST(AREA_ID AS VARCHAR(255))
      FROM AREA_ASSOC t2
      WHERE t1.ID_REVIEW = t2.ID
      FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '') AS AREA_ID
FROM REQUEST_WORKLOAD t1
```

Result:

```
ID_REVIEW | AREA_ID
-----------------
    11438 | 2
    23501 | 10, 15
    44677 | 8
```

What I'd like to do is instead of having numbers for `AREA_ID` is have the name of that area show up. The goal being to have:

```
ID_REVIEW | AREA_NM
-----------------
    11438 | State St.
    23501 | Main St., Second St.
    44677 | Adams Ave.
```

This `AREA_NM` information is contained in another table, called `AREA`. In a separate query, I can do a `LEFT JOIN` on table `AREA_ASSOC` to pull in the `AREA_NM`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [AREA_NM]
    FROM AREA_ASSOC 
    LEFT JOIN AREA ON
    AREA_ASSOC.AREA_ID = AREA.AREA_ID
```

I'm stumped as to how to get that `JOIN` into the `STUFF` function so I can get the area names. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the `join` in the subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r2.ID_REVIEW,
      STUFF( (SELECT N', ' + a2AREA_NM 
              FROM AREA_ASSOC aa2 JOIN
                   AREA a
                   ON aa2.AREA_ID = A.AREA_ID
              WHERE aa2.ID_REVIEW = r2.ID
              FOR XML PATH('')
             ), 1, 2, ''
           ) AS AREA_ID
FROM REQUEST_WORKLOAD rw
```